# JQuery Mobile prevent radio from being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I make a simple radio group using JQuery Mobile in that way:

```
        <fieldset id="current_status" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            {% for state in states %}
                <input type="radio" name="state-choice" id="state-{{ state.id }}" value="{{ state.id }}" data-code="{{ state.code }}"
                    {% if state == currentState %}checked="checked"{% endif %} 
                />
                <label for="state-{{ state.id }}">{{ state.description }}</label>
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
```

I need to validate changing, so I tried to use everything like:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#current_status label').click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            changeStatus($(this));
            return false;
        });

        $('#current_status input').click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            changeStatus($(this));
            return false;
        });
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    });
```

In my computer browser it works. 
But in mobile browser changing isn't prevented.
What could be a problem here?

Comment: I think this link might help you with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433871/how-to-get-checked-radio-buttons-value-in-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the problem is that your mobile browser doesn't trigger a click event, but instead a touch/tap event or such.

There's an event called "vclick" in jQuery Mobile to address this problem.

But in your case it might be a smarter idea to listen to a value change of your input fields.

```
$('#current_status input').on('change',function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  changeStatus($(this));
  return false;
});
```

Comment: True. But instead of a `change` event I used `vmousedown`. Also I replaced `click` with `vclick`.